# How to get access token with refresh token for YouTube Data API through Firebase Google authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, youtube-data-api

I wanted to build a web app that can view the user's YouTube channel info.
I used `Firebase` for authentication with Google and then stored the `accessToken` and `refreshToken` with the help of the code below.

```js
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    provider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(async (result) => {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);

        const accessToken = credential.accessToken;
        const refreshToken = result._tokenResponse.refreshToken;
        const user = result.user;
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", refreshToken);
        localStorage.setItem("user", user);
}
```

But after the expiry of the `accessToken`, it gets invalid.
So, I want to get the newly created `accessToken` with help of `refreshToken` but I could not find any way to retrieve that.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reauthenticatewithcredential

Comment: You can find details in below answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838154/retrieve-google-access-token-after-authenticated-using-firebase-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Firebase SDKs don't manage provider tokens as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45027069/13130697). Easiest way would be to [reauthenticate the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) but users may have to re-authorize your application if needed. Re-authenticating will return same `UserCredential` object as `result` in code snippet in your question.

Another option would be to use provider's own SDK and refreshing the token whenever required.

Comment: Can you give me some resource to login provider's own SDK, in this case Google with Firebase because reauthentication would be tedious for users.